# To find the nearest perfect square if the number entered is not a perfect square?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    cout << "Enter the number whose sqare root needs to be calculated";
    cin >> number;
    cout << "Square root of " << number << " is " << (int)sqrt((float)number)  << " OR " << sqrt((float)number) << endl;
    if( (int)sqrt((float)number) == sqrt((float)number) )
    cout << "The number is a perfect sqaure";
    else
    cout << "The number is not a perfect square";
    //To find the nearest perfect square if the number entered
   // is not a perfect square?

    return 0;
}
```

I hope what i have done to check the perfect squares is OK, but furthermore I want to
find out the number nearest perfect square if the number entered is not a perfect square
Any Ideas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, here is the better answer:

```
int number = 13;
int iRoot = static_cast<int>(sqrt(static_cast<float>(number)) + .5f);
```

You don't need to check between the ceil or the floor of which is greater, doing a simple round does the trick.

sqrt(13) is 3.6 and when you add .5 casts to 4.  sqrt(12) is 3.46 and when you add .5 casts to 3.  (we're trying to round, that's why we add the .5).  As you can see, when number is closer to the higher root, it'll give you a decimal greater than .5; when the number is closer to a lower value root, the decimal is less than .5, simple as that!

Comment: +1 for minimising the number of comparisons - although veredesmarald's solution is probably quicker to understand for those who have to maintain the code later!

Comment: Should probably use `double` rather than `float`, though, it's much more likely to be capable of precisely representing all values of `int`.

Comment: @leetNightshade, this seems like a nice trick...loking into it

Comment: @leetNightshade: The square root can have fractional part > .5 and still be closer to the smaller perfect square, e.g. for 380.3 (sqrt = 19.501...) your method returns 400 instead of 361. I *think* your method works for all integer inputs though.

Comment: Yes, seems to be a problem with taking the square root of a decimal. Taking the squareroot of .25 is .5, and .5 is .7. So, there are some things you would do differently with a decimal, though you could still do similar tricks, I think. I haven't gotten to test this completely out yet, but I think you might be able to get away with doing this: float number = 380.499; int iRoot = static_cast<int>(sqrt(static_cast<float>(static_cast<int>(number + .5f))) + .5f);  I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do it, but I have an exam to worry about for now. So, let me know what you think!

Comment: sorry about benig so late somthing came up, .5 is OK but what does .5f do ...trying to google it anyway ..Thanks

Comment: It simply rounds the number up if it has a decimal of at least .5 (when you cast the number to an integer anyway). 1.4 + .5 is still 1.9, and when cast to an integer is 1.  1.5 + .5 is 2.0 and when cast to an integer is 2.

Comment: Hmm...Thanks...smart way of doing things! leet I want to make this as an answer because its different and shorter.

Comment: Thanks, glad you liked my answer!

Answer (score 5):

Start by finding the floor and ceiling of the root:

```
float root = sqrt((float)number);
int floor = (int)root;
int ceil = floor + 1
```

Then just check which is closer out of `ceil * ceil` and `floor * floor`.

Comment: Actually, there is a faster way, check out my answer!

Answer (score 3):

Square the integers next to the root.

Answer (score 2):

Let `r` be `int(sqrt(double(number))+0.5)`. Then you need to check which of `(r-1)*(r-1)`, `r*r` and `(r+1)*(r+1)` is the nearest to `number`. That's all.

Comment: @munish: That's a way of rounding to the nearest integer, but you don't really want to do that in this case since it requires you to test three numbers instead of two.

Comment: This answer was close to a good answer, however you don't need to do any checks, the original solution for r would have worked by adding .5 (see my answer, which is basically the same thing, just with an example).

Answer (score 1):

you need to find out the two power of two for: `(int)sqrt((float)number)` and `((int)sqrt((float)number)+1)`, (denote them by d1,d2) and find out m`in{|number-d1|,|number-d2|}`.

also, to improve performance, I would have cached the float `sqrt((float)number)` as a variable and use it (instead of calculating again sqrt() )

Answer (score 1):

Use the same check to see if a number is a perfect square:

`if( (int)sqrt((float)number) == sqrt((float)number) )`

And apply it successively to the integers above and below the numbers specified by the user.

```
int delta=1;
int perfectSquare = 0;
bool perfectSquareFound = false;
while(!perfectSquareFound)
{
   int above = number+delta;
   int below = number-delta;
   float aboveSquareRoot = sqrt((float)above);
   float belowSquareRoot = sqrt((float)below);
   if( (int)aboveSquareRoot == aboveSquareRoot )
   {
      perfectSquareFound = true;
      perfectSquare = above;
   }
   else if( (int)belowSquareRoot == belowSquareRoot )
   {
      perfectSquareFound = true;
      perfectSquare = below;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a horribly inefficient method. You have turned two multiplications and a max into potentially thousands of iterations!

Comment: I completely agree! This is indeed a very inefficient method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer

```
int main()
{

    long long int n, ans;
    cin >> n;
    ans = round(sqrt(n));
    cout << ans<< endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Should be like (psuedo code),

```
int sqrtValue = (int)sqrt((float)number);  // store in a temporary value
int lowerPerfectSquare = pow(sqrtValue, 2);
int higerPerfectSquare = pow(sqrtValue + 1, 2);
int nearPerfectSquare = (higerPerfectSquare - number) < (number - lowerPerfectSquare)?
                        sqrtValue + 1 : sqrtValue;
```

Comment: Why do you calculate `sqrt` twice?

Comment: This calculates the largest perfect square less than number, not the closest.